# Issue with nested resource calls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Please excuse me if this is in some way obvious, but I can't seem to find any thing similar in the angularjs docs or on SO. I have an application where there is a table of data, including estimates by month. We are implementing something where you can drag and drop the estimate from one month to another as a way to make some quick changes. I'm running into an odd issue:

Resource:

```
function updatableResource(url){
  return $resource(url+":id/", {id: '@id'},
    {
      'update': {
        method:'PUT',
      },
    }
  );
}

// in API definition file
Estimate: foo.updatableResource('<URL>'),
```

That works fine, and I can call `$update` or `$save` with no issue normally

In this case though, I need to edit two things at the same time, and possibly even delete one. So I need to know if the first was successful in before I do the second. For example, if I move an estimate from one month to another with no estimate, I first make the new estimate and then delete the old one. I would think I could do something like this:

```
// source and target are objects that each contain an estimate from a different month.

successFunc = function() {
    source.estimate.$delete(
        function() {
            <refresh stuff>
        },
        function(rejection) {
            alert("Unable to delete source estimate.");
        }
    );
};

errorFunc = function(rejection) {
    <undo stuff>
    alert("Unable to add money to target estimate.");
};

// POST if new, PUT if updating
if (isNewEstimate) {
    target.estimate.$save(successFunc, errorFunc);
} else {
    target.estimate.$update(successFunc, errorFunc);
}
```

So in this code, the estimate creation/update works fine, but I cannot call any $resource calls on the source estimate in the success function. I get the error `TypeError: source.estimate.$delete is not a function` If I call it outside that function (at the same level as the target save/update call) it works though.

In my research I found something which sort of worked:

```
Api.Estimate.delete(source.estimate, 
<success and failure functions>
...
```

That made the deletion work, but nothing else seems to recognize the deletion and I need to do an expensive manual re-query in order for it to work. Is there something odd about scope since it's in a callback function? I just can't figure out why it won't work within that function...

EDIT:

Upon further testing, it seems to be an issue with the objects themselves:

```
source.estimate
Object
    amount: 12345
    date: "2017-02-25"
    foo: "ABC"
    id: 4715
    bar: 987
    baz: 123
    __proto__: Object

target.estimate
d
    $promise: undefined
    $resolved: true
    amount: 12345
    date: "2017-03-25"
    foo: "ABC"
    id: 4716
    bar: 987
    baz: 123
    __proto__: Object
```

So the target one, which is of type `d`, seems to work while the source one, which is just a standard object, doesn't. If I reverse the drag direction, I'm given the same type of result. Source is always an object, and target is always `d` (which I assume is because of minified JS).

Comment: I've run into this issue when using $resource... which is why i switched to straight $http, but if you Console.log(source.estimate) does it actually have a value at that point?

Comment: As I added in my edit above, the object seemed normal (as in it had the fields and values expected) but it turns out the actual objects are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually turned out to be related to the plugin I was using to get the objects. For some reason it was mangling one of them, and while it had the same properties it wasn't a proper `$resource` anymore, which is why I couldn't call the function. It just seemed like it was related to the calling layout because of the order in which I was calling some functions.

Answer (score 0):

The instance methods of $resource objects are promises and can be chained with standard chaining methods:

```
$scope.resource1 = updatableResource().get({id: 1});
$scope.resource2 = updatableResource().get({id: 2});

$q.all([$scope.resource1.$promise, $scope.resource2.$promise])
  .then(function(resArray) {
     var res1 = resArray[0];
     var res2 = resArray[1];
     //Process results
     //Return promise to chain
     return $q.all([res1.$update(), res2.$update()]);
}).then(function(resArray) {
     var res1 = resArray[0];
     var res2 = resArray[1];
     //Do next thing
});
```

> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.
>
> It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)